# Request to migrate a question to Raspberry Pi declined

Tags: discussion, questions, migration

I recently flagged a question to be migrated to [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).

> [Backup data rate on Raspberry Pi maxing out at 5 Mb/s. Why?](https://superuser.com/questions/455541/backup-data-rate-on-raspberry-pi-maxing-out-at-5-mb-s-why)

But it was declined with the following explanation.

> don't really migrate to betas to allow them to organically plant their feet

I really don't think that this applies in this situation though as the Raspberry Pi site is currently 49 days into public beta. While the question was asked *yesterday*.

If this question was asked three months ago, *before* Raspberry Pi entered public beta I could see, and would even agree, with the reason behind it's decline.

However in this case, we have a brand new question asked on site A when it is more relevant to site B. Why not migrate it?

The same approach is taken with [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Stack Overflow migrates questions that are on-topic for Code Review to them, even though they are still in public beta.

In conclusion, *why not migrate?* `/rant`

Comment: [Raspberry Pi is now on-topic through community consensus.](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5984/can-we-make-raspberry-pi-questions-off-topic-and-avoid-hurting-raspberry-pi-se)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What the response means is that we generally don't migrate questions to beta sites *at all*, unless the question is already distinctly off-topic for Super User and specifically on-topic for that beta site.

New sites need to grow on their own accord. Poaching an established site is not an effective way to get new users. Furthermore, it is a very confusing user experience for the question asker when their question which was *on topic* is suddenly moved to a new site they've never seen before and may have no interest in participating in.

On Super User, we frown on migrating questions away if they're on-topic here. Flags requesting that questions be migrated to the Raspberry Pi site will be declined if the question is on-topic for Super User.

That being said, if you see a Raspberry Pi question that has been around for a while (like, *several weeks*) and has no answers, it's fine to leave a polite comment letting the question asker know that there's a site for that subject. But leave it up to them to request the migration - it's their choice to make.

Comment: Hmmm... I thought it was bad etiquette to migrate old questions?

Comment: @BryanDunsmore we don't like to migrate really old questions, but if it's middle-aged and the person who asked the question _wants_ it moved, we're happy to grant that request.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Sorry for all the trouble. I just thought that our site could be a little bit more helpful to the asker. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question though! =D

Comment: @BryanDunsmore I understand that sentiment, and agree. We feel that it's more helpful to the asker though to provide a consistent experience and not migrate their question unnecessarily. Thanks for keeping an eye out for users and asking about your concerns!

Comment: @BryanDunsmore - "Old" in this context is months/years not weeks.

Answer (score 5):

In many respects, this question (and the response) goes to the heart of a concern I'm already developing over the SO family of sites and many of the Area51 proposals - fragmentation.

Yes, the RPi question would be more **directly** on-topic at RPi.SE(beta) than here.  But (as the responses show) the "turf war" is already in place with the view that RPi questions are also on-topic here (and probably elsewhere too).

Likewise there are several A51 proposals relating to robotics (in one form or the other) when a combined Robotics proposal would make most sense.

Personally, I'd rather see a smaller number of well-scoped but broad-topic sites, than a bigger number of niche sites that will probably wither.

Answer (score 3):

Raspberry Pi questions are perfectly on topic for Super User.

The question was only asked yesterday, so there's no need for a rush to migrate it out into a beta. If the user asking thought it should have been posted to Raspberry Pi instead, maybe.

Still, even then, public or private, it's a beta and if they want to survive as a site, they shouldn't be scavenging for posts from others.

Comment: I'm not scavenging from other sites. I just thought that this question would get more answers from a site _entirely devoted to the topic._ =/

Comment: It's been one day only for the question