# Why was question about the space required for installing Raspbian closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, close-reasons

Question: [How much space does Raspbian use?](https://superuser.com/questions/504986/how-much-space-does-raspbian-use)

Why was this closed? The Raspberry Pi is a real computer and couldn't find the information elsewhere?

If this actually should be closed, is there any other SE I could ask this question on?

Comment: There’s three main reasons it could/would have been closed: **(1)** Rπ is not quite a computer like a laptop or desktop, it is closer to an electronics project, **(2)** Most any software questions are just generic Linux question which have at least two or three dedicated SE sites, and **(3)** There is already a dedicated Rπ SE site. **(2/3)** SU is generally perceived more as a WinTel site since Linux and Mac/Apple have their own sites while Windows and general consumer computer electronics do not.

Comment: @Synetech: [Raspberry Pi is now on-topic through community consensus](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5984/can-we-make-raspberry-pi-questions-off-topic-and-avoid-hurting-raspberry-pi-se).

Comment: @TomWijsman Linux questions are also on topic here. I am active on U&L.SE as well and tend to ask the more hardcore technical Linux questions there while simpler (often GUI related) questions I would ask on SO. See [this discussion](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291/do-i-ask-here-or-on-super-user/1002#1002) on meta U&L.

Comment: FYI: I posted a *similar* question on Rpi.SE: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/918/do-i-need-to-buy-an-sd-card-with-an-os-preloaded-on-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've reopened the question, it's on topic here, as are all Raspberry Pi questions.

We have a site dedicated to RasPi as well:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can such RPi question be on-topic on our community? They're just duplicates of more generic Linux questions, and hence it has been rightfully closed. Enough questions ask about this...

Comment: 1) If you say *"They're just duplicates of more generic Linux questions, and hence it has been rightfully closed"* – then please point me to such a duplicate and we'll close it as that. 2) It was closed as off topic, which simply isn't true and gives the wrong impression that Raspberri Pi questions aren't welcome here. 3) Asking how much space a distribution uses is definitely based on an actual problem. You want to know because you need an appropriate amount of memory for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @TomWijsman I asked this question to know how large a SD-card I needed to buy for the RPi, so I don't see why it isn't a practical problem.

Comment: @TomWijsman Raspberry Pi questions have always been on topic here, and it's [been made clear before](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5336/48078), so, we've decided on that (or, actually, no decision had to be made really). Also, you can use `df` once you've installed it, which kind of defeats the purpose of asking the question – the image you can download is not the same size as the space it takes up after being installed. If you think the question doesn't show enough research effort, you're free to downvote it of course.

Comment: @slhck: [Raspberry Pi is now on-topic through community consensus](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5984/can-we-make-raspberry-pi-questions-off-topic-and-avoid-hurting-raspberry-pi-se)