# Can you add the UNIX&Linux SE to the available migration groups?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

Can you add the UNIX&Linux SE to the available migration groups?  It has a lot of other groups but in some cases allowing a transfer to that group might be preferable.

Comment: Preferable to what? Over what?

Comment: to remaining in this group of course.

Comment: Why? Questions about Unix and Linux are almost always on-topic for Super User. I see no reason to add a migration path. If a user wants their question migrated they can flag for a moderator to move it for them.

Comment: I thought the user having a kernel rebuild problem would be better served on the UNIX&Linux SE... http://superuser.com/questions/633415/trouble-compiling-linux-kernel-from-source

Comment: @mdpc No reason to migrate without the asking user explicitly wanting it.

Comment: FWIW there were only four migrations to U&L in the last 90 days (probably because there's almost never a reason to migrate as random mentioned). The five slots we have are used by MSU (by convention) and the top four migration destinations. Which of Web Apps (83 migrations), SO (57), Android (54) and SF (38) would you remove to add U&L?

Answer (score 7):

Unix and Linux related questions are all on topic for Super User. They're fine to stay here. (So long as they fit the other requirements of being on topic/in scope, not being a smartphone, smartfridge, [etc](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).)

The only time a question is migrated from here to the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site is if the user asking the question requested so because they thought the audience might be better for them.

Other than that, moderators will decline migration requests.

Comment: “Unix and Linux related questions are all on topic for Super User”. Sweet, Beagleboard and Pi and mobile phones and clusters and Kerberos servers are on-topic on SU now? Not that SU should have a migration path — *most* U&L questions have always been on-topic on SU — but *all* is new.

Comment: @Gilles are mobile phone questions on topic on U&L? Pi has always been on topic on SU as far as I know.

Comment: @terdon On [unix.se], Unix is on-topic regardless of which device you run it in, be it a PC or a mobile phone or a toaster. Few mobile phones run a unix variant (Android isn't a unix, nor is iOS unless you escape its jail — I don't think any smartphone is sold with a unix out of the box at the moment, unless the N900 is still around). Regarding SU, I wonder why a Pi would be on-topic but not an iPhone.

Comment: @Gilles OK, I thought you meant Android. As for Pi, it is by any definition a computer that can run arbitrary code, it is not a phone and it has not been hobbled by its manufacturers like phones have. Why would it not be on topic? See [here](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5984/151431) for a relevant discussion.